# Why is my submenu not aligned with my parent li?

Tags: css, web, menu

Heres my website unbotttled.com and the categories sub menu does not align with its parent categories? Is it to do with the padding, is there another way to solve this other than removing the padding? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not positioned correctly because the `li` it is inside of has padding of 15px. So it is to the right by 15px.

Add this CSS to the ul sub-menu `margin-left:-15px`

Comment: You are most welcome! Good luck with your website! (If you could be so kind as to upvote my answer, that would help me out :) )

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` and the `<ul>` are both being padded by the containing `<li>` "Categories". To help you understand - If you look closely the drop down is getting lined up to the left edge of "Categories" because of the containg `<li>`'s `padding:15px`.

There are a few ways to fix this, using a negative margin is one:

```
 #menuleft ul li:hover ul {  
 display: block;  
 position: fixed;  
 visibility: visible;  
 width: 130px;  
 padding: 0;  
 padding-top: 20px;  
 margin-left: -15px;
```

Having a thorough understanding of the CSS Box Model is imperative for modern Web Development. It's fairly easy to understand.
Learn about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html